# How to change background-color of WordPress-Theme on hover over words

Tags: css, hover, wordpress-theming, background-color

I work on a WordPress site for a friend and use the free Kadence Theme for that.

I want to display some text and when i hover over some of the words inside it, i want the whole background-colour of the site to change.

For that i identified an element to address with DevTools:

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="site wp-site-blocks">
```

It works just fine, but ONLY if you hover fast enough from one span-element to another.
Try it out. First move your cursor slowly (no change of the background color). Then move the cursor quickly (background changes).

Why is that?

```css
/* color change of text on hover */

h1>span:hover {
  color: #dddddd;
}

/* color change of background on hover */

#wrapper:has(#rule1:hover) {
  background: red;
}

#wrapper:has(#rule2:hover) {
  background: blue;
}

#wrapper:has(#rule3:hover) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="site wp-site-blocks">
<section class="intro">
  <h1>Rae magnim
    <span id="rule1">volorrum</span>
    <span id="rule2">recate</span>
    <span id="rule3">parchil</span> ipsandiscias est labo.
  </h1>
</section>
</div>
```

I also tried in vain to address the class instead like so:

```css
.site:has(#rule1:hover) {
  background: black;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a rough structure of the #wrapper

Comment: Ah, it was erased from my initial comment.

The wrapper looks like this:

<div id="wrapper" class="site p-site-blocks">

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the background of the site when hovering an element using css only. Generally speaking a child cannot affect a parent in css, it's the other way around. It is only when using [relative selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Selector_list#forgiving_relative_selector_list) that you can achieve it. Selectors such as: `+` and `>`.

With javascript that's a different story.

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".affects-wrapper");
var wrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper");
list.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    wrapper.classList.add(item.id + "-class")
  })
  item.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    wrapper.classList.remove(item.id + "-class")
  })
})
```

```css
/* color change of text on hover */

h1>span:hover {
  color: #dddddd;
}


/* color change of background on hover */

.rule1-class {
  background: red;
}

.rule2-class {
  background: blue;
}

.rule3-class {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <section class="intro">
    <h1>Rae magnim
      <span id="rule1" class="affects-wrapper">volorrum</span>
      <span id="rule2" class="affects-wrapper">recate</span>
      <span id="rule3" class="affects-wrapper">parchil</span> ipsandiscias est labo.
    </h1>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is really a nice work around.

But i still wonder if there is a solution via css, because the selector :has should do exactly what you say is not possible (https://css-tricks.com/the-css-has-selector/).

And in the example i posted, it actually works, only unfortunately it has this glitch.

So i keep this question open.